# Fancybox link dont work after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, fancybox

I have created fancybox form :

```
$("a.productForm").fancybox({
    'hideOnOverlayClick' : true,
    'modal' : true,
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,
    'showCloseButton' : false,
    'padding' : 0,
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'frameWidth': 717,
    'frameHeight': 900,
    'overlayOpacity': 0.4,
    'centerOnScroll' : false,
    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': {
    dataFilter: function(data) {
        return $(data).find('#form_wrapper')[0];}
}
});
```

You can see in [this](http://mazdas.lv/1473-ford-galaxy-lietotas-rezerves-dalas-autokapseta-sroti) page how it works.

To view my fancybox form, press please green button :

[image]

As you can see all works just fine in this page, but my code wont work in page, where products is loading with ajax. You can see [this](http://mazdas.lv/1250-alfa-romeo-autokapseta-lietotas-rezerves-dalas-detalas-auto) page.

When you press green button in this page, fancybox just wont show up, instead it goes straight to the link. What could be wrong?

Maybe I have to apply fancbox code to this link after it is loaded whit ajax?

Comment: I used to fix this with the livequery plugin in jQuery 1.4. But I think that jQuery 1.7 has better options already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the $("a.productForm").fancybox(...) in the ajax success callback, after the html data has been received and added to the dom.

Here's a simple example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(data){
    $('#newest_desc').html(data); // Here you insert data which I'm expecting to be a string with html into the tab with the id "newest_desc". I got that from your website. Not sure if it's correct though.
    $("a.productForm").fancybox(...) // Here is where you call the fancybox function because now you know that the element a.productForm is available.
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @iKaspars I've added a simple example. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will look around. Only thing is that I didnt create that plugin to get products with ajax. That way I think it will be hard to find that code part where they are getting products with ajax. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some errors in your javascript. This causes the link to be followed by the browser.

Install Firebug if you don't have it already, enable the console, and click "persist". This way the errror won't disappear when the browser changes page, and you'll be able to see the error.